# Typescript enum, interface and mapping

Tags: typescript

**In TypeScript, in an array or similar data structure, how can I map a string to an id, while ensuring that only a certain range of ids is allowed?**

Here is what I want to do. This works fine. However, I am wondering if there is a more concise way of achieving this?

```
enum ETypeId {
    alpha  = "a",
    beta   = "b",
    gamma  = "g"
}

interface IType {
    id:     ETypeId,
    title:  string,
}

myTypes: IType[] = [
    { id: ETypeId.alpha, title: "Alpha" },
    { id: ETypeId.beta,  title: "Beta"  },
    { id: ETypeId.gamma, title: "Gamma" }
];
```

As is, I have to do the following to get from the `id` to the `title`:

```
function getTypeForTypeId( typeId: ETypeId ): IType {
    return myTypes.find( type => type.id == typeId );
}
```

**Can I use a different data structure that makes some of the above code more concise, or is this already as good as it gets?**

---

Explanation:

- `"a"` is what gets stored in my database
- `ETypeId.alpha` is how I access it in my code
- `"Alpha"` is what gets displayed to the user.

Answer (score 14):

Agree with [Sergi Dote Teixidor's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50069150/7597651) answer that [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is the best option for such problem. However, based on the described problem, I think that it could be simplified to `Map<ETypeId, string>`:

```
enum ETypeId {
    alpha  = "a",
    beta   = "b"
}

const types: Map<ETypeId, string> = new Map( [
   [ ETypeId.alpha, "Alpha" ],
   [ ETypeId.beta, "Beta" ],
]);
```

Just in case you want to initialize your structure once and make TypeScript protect you from changing values inside your map:

```
enum ETypeId {
    alpha  = "a",
    beta   = "b"
}

interface ReadonlyMap<TKey, TValue> {
    get(key: TKey):TValue;
}

const types: ReadonlyMap<ETypeId, string> = new Map( [
   [ ETypeId.alpha, "Alpha" ],
   [ ETypeId.beta, "Beta" ],
]);

// Static analyzer error if you try to change the value:
types.set(ETypeId.alpha, "NewValue");
```

Answer (score 11):

you can use a map:

1. you can retrieve directly any element
2. you can loop all elements if you want

example:

```
enum ETypeId {
    alpha  = "a",
    beta   = "b",
    gamma  = "g"
}

interface IType {
    id:     ETypeId,
    title:  string,
}

const myMap: Map<string, IType> = new Map( [
   [ ETypeId.alpha,  { id: ETypeId.alpha, title: "Alpha" } ],
   [ ETypeId.beta,  { id: ETypeId.beta,  title: "Beta"  } ],
   [ ETypeId.gamma, { id: ETypeId.gamma, title: "Gamma" } ]
]);

console.log(myMap.get(ETypeId.alpha)) // -> {id: "a", title: "Alpha"}
```